# How to extract Specific part of a string whose starting substring and endsubstring is known but internal string length varies

Tags: java

I have string coming from db whose structure looks like this

"-$ErrorCode$-0-$ErrorCodeEnd$--$Errortext$-Success-$ErrorTextEnd$--$val1$-test160-$val1End$--$LIST1$--$val2$--test1160--$val2End--$List2End$-";

string  between substring -$tagName$- and -$tagNameEnd$- its length varies and I have to extract that substring and have to store in another string

Eg string between tag -$ErrorCode$- and -$ErrorCodeEnd$- is "0" and i have to store that in string named Error;

Is there any method to do that in java1.8 code

Note: string that i have to extract its length varies
eg:  ErrorCode which is shown 0 here can be 100000 or 3234324343242 or any thing.
eg2: Errortext which is shown success here can be anything like "notFound" or "notExists" or anything

I am unable to find any solution right now. do provide the java_code if someone finds the solution of this problem

Comment: Given that your tags are never nested a simple `String.split("\\$")` should get you going, assuming that the values never contain`$`.

Comment: Please, share your **attempt** and specify the problem you've encountered. Every question on StackOverflow is expected to demonstrate an effort. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex with Positive Lookbehind and Positive Lookahead to implement the extraction of the substring:

```java
public String getContent(String input, String start, String end) {
    // Compile a regex pattern for the given start substring and end substring
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=" + start + ").*?(?=" + end + ")");
    // Use the pattern to match input string
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    if(matcher.find())
        // Matcher.group() returns the matched substring
        return matcher.group();
    return null;
}
```

Sample usage (note that we need to escape `$`, since it's a special symbol in regex):

```java
String input = "-$ErrorCode$-123123-$ErrorCodeEnd$--$Errortext$-Success-$ErrorTextEnd$--$val1$-test160-$val1End$--$LIST1$--$val2$--test1160--$val2End--$List2End$-";
System.out.println(getContent(input, "-\\$ErrorCode\\$-", "-\\$ErrorCodeEnd\\$-"));
System.out.println(getContent(input, "-\\$Errortext\\$-", "-\\$ErrorTextEnd\\$-"));
System.out.println(getContent(input, "-\\$LIST1\\$-", "-\\$List2End\\$-"));
```

Output:

```
123123
Success
-$val2$--test1160--$val2End-
```